# How to combine nested duplicate dictionary values within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested, duplicates

I have a following data structure, array of dictionaries

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Some Name 1",
    "topics": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Topic Name",
                    "topics": [],
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Topic Name",
                    "topics": [],
                 }
     ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Some Name 2",
    "topics": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Topic Name",
                    "topics": [],
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Topic Name",
                    "topics": [],
                 }
     ]
},
```

[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Some Name 2",
"topics": [
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Topic Name 1",
"topics": [],
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Topic Name 2",
"topics": [],
}
]
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Some Name 1",
"topics": [
{
"id": 3,
"name": "Topic Name",
"topics": [],
},
{
"id": 3,
"name": "Topic Name",
"topics": [],
}
]
},

I want to essentially be able to combine the arrays within each dictionary if I have the same id, so for each dictionary i will have higher level dictionary items being the same and essentially combine those together to avoid duplication. Preferably i would like it to be recursively being that in case the topics within topics are also duplicate (you can assume the order is always respected).

I would appreciate if you could share a solution to this

Comment: Neat problem. What have you tried in order to solve it? What went wrong? Please post your very best attempt in a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have tried using reduce, but have not managed to have a good minimal solution yet

Comment: It's really difficult to actually know what are you trying to achieve here, could you maybe organize the code and clarify the question a little? Maybe add an example of what you are trying to do?